# SQL Syntax Error Integers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I`m trying to have a form that writes to a mysql database using php and html.  After submitting the form I get the error

> MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '', '1', '1362154007', '127.0.0.1'' at line 2

The code to the submission php file is

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql="INSERT INTO entries (summoner, role, level, time, ip)
VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['summoner']) . "', " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['role']) . "', '" . intval($_POST['level']) . "', '" . time() . "', '" . $ip . "'"; 
if (!mysql_query($sql)) die("MySQL error: " . mysql_error());
echo "1 record added";
?>
```

and the code to line two is

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "ratchet132", "password", "lookingforq") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("lookingforq", $con) or die(mysql_error());
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
?>
```

The error only occurs with integers that are not submitted by the html form (although the level is submitted by it, but it seems to due to the same reason as the others, not the forms).  I'm thinking this is probably an error with how I have my MYSQL table set up but I can't figure out what I've done wrong.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: You have no `'` before the role.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an extra single quote in your integer value,

```
VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['summoner']) . "', " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['role']) . "', '" . intval($_POST['level']) . "', '" . time() . "', '" . $ip . "'"; 
                                                                                                                ^ HERE
```

My suggestion is to store the values in variable first so it is easy to debug the code, eg

```
$summoner = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['summoner']);
$role = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['role']);
$intV = intval($_POST['level']);
$sTime = time();
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql="INSERT INTO entries (summoner, role, level, time, ip) 
      VALUES ('$summoner', $role, $intV, $sTime,'$ip' )')";
```

Use `PDO` or `MySQLi` extension so you can paramaterized the query. The link below talks about `SQL Injection` but it also shows there the usage of `PDO` and `MySQLi` Extension.

- [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I get this now instead:

`MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', 1', '1362154579', '127.0.0.1'' at line 2`

Comment: The ***only*** solution here is to use binded parameters and prepared statements. This is the closest answer to that solution.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk yep, I added a link on my answer which shows how prepared statements are used. `:D`

Comment: I'm getting this at the moment.

`MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 2`

If I remove those characters it results in a

`MySQL error: Unknown column 'two' in 'field list'`

Comment: oh what query are you execute? there is no `two` on the column you have shown.

Comment: Would you like to look at the form code or what I currently have for the actual php action?

Comment: if you may.. hey, who don't you want to use `PDO` or `MySQLi`?

Comment: It seems even more confusing haha :P

Comment: ok, can youpost the whole query you have executed?

Comment: Submit.php's code:
`<?php
require 'connection.php';
$summoner = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['summoner']);
$role = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['role']);
$intV = intval($_POST['level']);
$sTime = time();
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql="INSERT INTO entries (summoner, role, level, time, ip) 
      VALUES ('$summoner', $role, $intV, $sTime,'$ip' )";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) die("MySQL error: " . mysql_error());
echo "1 record added";
?>`

Comment: HTML

`        <form action="submit.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="summoner">
        <input type="text" name="role">
        <input type="text" name="level">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-success">
        </form>`

Comment: which of this are integer? summoner, role, level, time, ip

Comment: Level and time, ip and the rest are varchar.

Comment: and which means summoner, role are integers. here, try this, `INSERT INTO entries (summoner, role, level, time, ip) VALUES ($summoner, $role, '$intV', '$sTime','$ip')`

Comment: IT WORKS! :D THANK YOU SO MUCH

edit: When I type in the first textbox text instead of a number (first textbox is for the varchar) it results in the error 

`MySQL error: Unknown column 'my' in 'field list'`

Comment: so the problem has been solved? `:D`

Comment: Half-solved haha.  It works but only when I enter numbers within the html forms (summoner and role).

`MySQL error: Unknown column 'my' in 'field list'` is what I get if I enter "my"

Comment: as you can see, the value is not wrap with single quote since it is an integer. i guess you need to trap the user inputs before inserting on the database.

Comment: The fields I'm having problems with are the var char ones, not the integer ones anymore, but if I insert integers into the var char forms it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why you wrap int value in quotes?

```
'" . intval($_POST['level']) . "'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `'`. Try:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO entries (summoner, role, level, time, ip)
VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['summoner']) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['role']) . "', '" . intval($_POST['level']) . "', " . time() . ", '" . $ip . "'";
```

Comment: This got me somewhere! :D It solved the problem but now it says
`MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2`
I'm thinking there's an extra comma or something that's causing it?  I can't find it though

Comment: removed the `'` from `time()`. Try now. It's hard to tell without seeing your database setup.